# Any way to escalate webscraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am scraping a website, but it's taking too long to iterate row by row. Is there any way, instead of iterating, of just reading in the whole table?

This is the code I have:

```
table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='tblDocumentosEnviados']//tr")
for row in range(len(table)):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                                   "//table[@id='tblDocumentosEnviados']//tr[" + str(
                                                                       row) + "]//td[text()='Rendimentos e Amortizações']/following-sibling::td[.//span[text()='Ativo']]/following-sibling::td//a[@title='Download do Documento']"))).click()
```

Here is the website i am **scraping** from:
https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/abrirGerenciadorDocumentosCVM

Comment: Just read `//table[@id='tblDocumentosEnviados']`, not loop over and find each of the `tr` tags

Answer (score 1):

You already have `table` as a variable. You don't need to use the driver to further look up each row.

You can use BeautifulSoup, for example to parse through the table text

Comment: would you mind sharing some code of how to use BeautifulSoup for this task? I am used to Selenium, but BS not so much

Comment: I suppose it's not really clear what you're trying to do, but the beautifulsoup docuemntation covers enough details. The general idea is to take the text content of the `table` element you've found, then find the `tr` elements within **it** (using find functions) rather than using the selenium driver

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Pandas dataframe from table

```
t = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='tblDocumentosEnviados']").get_attribute('outerHTML')
table_df = pd.read_html(t)
```

Comment: There are two href at the last column (Ações), how can I add each of the hrefs to the DF?

Comment: do you want to split the last column in two individual columns ?

Comment: Yes, split and extract the href from the website, because the DF doesnt have the links.

Comment: for splitting you can use `df['<colname>'].str.split('<delimiter>',expand=True)`.

Comment: in the case of the missing a href value, there is an empty column or the column wasn't created ?

Comment: I shared the rest of the code i use, where i click the href titled 'Download do Documento' when there is 'Rendimentos e Amortizações' on column Tipo.

So i need to download a file from this website, only when it is 'Rendimentos e Amortizações'